# how to check email id entered is registered with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

m using adaptive payment method

i want to trace out weather email id entered is registered with Paypal or not 
 is there any way to trace it???
 check email id entered is weather registered with Paypal 
is there any API or example??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GetVerifiedStatus` [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/).To use this API, you will need to create an adaptive application [here](https://www.paypal-apps.com)

Comment: Above links are broken. Read further on links below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACVersionHistory/#adaptive-account-changes-in-paypal-v960

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/adaptive-accounts/PayPal-Adaptive-Accounts-API-Release-Notes-1-2-0/