# Paypal API to check email is already registered or not? Help to set advance permission

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to check email is already registered with paypal or not using paypal adaptive create account api.

I also want help for advance permission. Where can I set advance permission for GetVerifiedStatus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check email id entered is registered with Paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470517/how-to-check-email-id-entered-is-registered-with-paypal)

Comment: Yes, I used this api. But it ask 'NAME' for 'MatchCriteria'. Here I want to pass 'NONE' But don;t know hot to set advance permission